# webkitfullscreenchange event for iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, fullscreen

```
/* works on all elements except iframes */
document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function() {
   alert("hello world");
}, false); 

/* never triggers even when iFrame enters full screen */
myIframe.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function() {
   alert("hello iframe");
}, false);
```

I am not able to get event listener webkitfullscreenchange event to trigger for iframes. iFrame is under the same origin. Does anyone know how to get this work? Thanks.

Comment: It works for me under the latest Chrome (15). Are you requesting based on a user event and is myIframe defined before the binding?

Comment: I realized my problem.  Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone ask for the same issue, `allowfullscreen=true` on iframe must be setted

([https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko:FullScreenAPI#fullscreenchange_event](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko%3aFullScreenAPI#fullscreenchange_event))